# Codeigniter WWW Root

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

I would like to add a folder called html at the root. In this folder i will have the images, js, css ect. I did .htaccess in the root with:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$    html/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) html/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

i also had copied over the index.php from the root to the html path. Inside the html/.htaccess file I have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Also inside the index.php file, I had changed the path's to:

```
$system_path = '../system';
$application_folder = '../application';
```

The result comes with a 404 error page styled from codeigniter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the URL helper always will fix the issue, Make sure your js and images are in root.
Ex.

```
<?php $this->load->helper('url');?>
<link href="<?php echo site_url('style.css')?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: but if i do it like that. that would require js, styles, images in the root along with application & system and not inside my created html folder wouldnt it? Although its more structural for me than convenience.. im just wondering for personal experiance.

Comment: Yes you are right, check this link for your requirements http://www.maheshchari.com/codeigniter-url-helper-part1/